# C# Parse a list of values into two fields

Tags: c#, parsing

OK, I have a block of incoming text like this... (either in a serial stream, or a richTextBox)
Be gentle - Only day 3 of C#

Approx 50 lines delimited by LF

```
LASTKNOWN:041A
INVERT:041E
INCOUNT:0422
INZERO:042A
OUTCOUNT:0434
OUTZERO:043C
```

And my crude beginner's attempt to parse these one line at a time... is to find the keyword (e.g. LASTKNOWN), and push it (by literal) into a list, then dig out the trailing value and push it into a second synchronised list of integers.
The  goes into a synchronised Int16 list

(Of course I expect this could be more elegant with structs in a list - it I'm not up to that yet!)

```
index = rtbReceived.Find("LASTKNOWN");
if (index > 0)
{   // assign the value from the string into the local variable lists
    fieldName.Add("LASTKNOWN");
    fieldValue.Add(<theValue>);
}
```

**There has to be a better way to do this iteratively**... with variable length keywords / values etc.

Help appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, `Dictionary` would be the best choice for you.

Comment: You can split input by 'new line' to get the lines, then split each line by colon to get key-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, you could use a combination of splits. You could also use this regex approach to put the keyvaluepairs into a dictionary.

```
string sInput = @"LASTKNOWN:041A
INVERT:041E
INCOUNT:0422
INZERO:042A
OUTCOUNT:0434
OUTZERO:043C";
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<key>[^:]+):(?<val>.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(sInput);

Dictionary<String, String> lst = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    lst.Add(m.Groups["key"].Value, m.Groups["val"].Value);
}
```

The only thing to keep in mind with Dictionary is that you cannot have duplicate keys. Once you have it in a dictionary, it's not unlike an array that is indexed by strings. Here are some samples of how you can use it:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> item in lst)
{
    string sKey = item.Key;
    string sValue = item.Value;
}

string sLastKnownValue = lst["LASTKNOWN"];
```

If you are just looking for one you could bypass iteration like so:

```
string sInput = @"LASTKNOWN:041A
INVERT:041E
INCOUNT:0422
INZERO:042A
OUTCOUNT:0434
OUTZERO:043C";

Regex r = new Regex(@"^LASTKNOWN:(?<val>.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match m = r.Match(sInput);
string sValue = String.Empty;
if (m.Success)
    sValue = m.Value;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the check.